# Draw a vertical flow chart

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, tikz-trees

I would like to draw a Diagram like the one in the attached picture.
[image]

Comment: Welcome at tex.sx. Thanks for providing the image, it shows what you want. According to your tags, you intent to work with tikz. Could you add the tikz code that you have such that we can identify where and how you need help? Your "question" (if it can be called that way) is quite unclear. Please show your current efforts and ask specific questions if you run into trouble.

Comment: Have you already tried something? You can probably find some ideas on [TeXample.net](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/) and also on [this site](http://tex.stackexchange.com/search?tab=relevance&q=%5btikz-pgf%5d%20flow%20chart) as well. Also: What is the question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is one alternative via matrix nodes from tikz, where the box can be adjusted via `minimum height` and `minimum width` and `text width` in the box style and the nodes separation can be determined by the `column sep` and `row sep`.

[image]

Codes

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,shapes,arrows,positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[boxes/.style={draw, rectangle,%
                thick,minimum height=1cm, rounded corners,
                minimum width=1cm, orange, text=black,
                text width=25mm, align=center}]
  \matrix (mat) [matrix of nodes, nodes=boxes, column sep=2cm, row sep=1cm] 
  {
         &                &     Evans              \\ 
 Harry   &  Petter        &                        \\
         &                &     Robert             \\ 
  };  
\draw [very thick, blue, ->](mat-2-1)--(mat-2-2);
\draw [very thick, blue, ->](mat-2-2.east)--(mat-1-3.west);
\draw [very thick, blue, ->](mat-2-2.east)--(mat-3-3.west);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```